# Multiple-Entity GroupBy not dishing out Distinct Values - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, distinct

I currently have a fairly long LINQ statement which pulls data from two tables: Employee, and Time. This IQueryable is displayed in a Telerik RadGrid via the Grids DataSource. My goal is to show the Employee's Hours for that Period and allow the User to upload the Approved Timesheet to the system.

```
public static IQueryable GetUnimportedTimesheets()
{
    DataContext tData = new DataContext();

    var Times = tData.system_Times.Where(a => a.Status == 0)
        .OrderBy(a => a.Period)
        .ThenBy(a => a.system_Employee.LName)
        .GroupBy(a => new { a.Period , a.EmployeeID  } )
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Times = x.FirstOrDefault(),
            TotalReg = tData.system_Times
                .Where(b => b.EmployeeID == x.Key.EmployeeID && b.PayCode == "211")
                .Sum(b => b.Hours),
            TotalOT = tData.system_Times
                .Where(b => b.EmployeeID == x.Key.EmployeeID && b.PayCode == "212")
                .Sum(b => b.Hours),
            TotalTrav = tData.system_Times
                .Where(b => b.EmployeeID == x.Key.EmployeeID && b.PayCode == "214")
                .Sum(b => b.Hours),
            TotalSub = tData.system_Times
                .Where(b => b.EmployeeID == x.Key.EmployeeID && b.PayCode == "251")
                .Sum(b => b.Hours),
            FName = tData.system_Employees
                .Where(b => b.EmployeeID == x.Key.EmployeeID)
                .Select(c => c.FName).FirstOrDefault(),
            LName = tData.system_Employees
                .Where(b => b.EmployeeID == x.Key.EmployeeID)
                .Select(c => c.LName).FirstOrDefault(),
            Div = tData.system_Employees
                .Where(b => b.EmployeeID == x.Key.EmployeeID)
                .Select(c => c.Dept).FirstOrDefault(),
            AccID = tData.Pmsystem_Employees
                .Where(b => b.EmployeeID == x.Key.EmployeeID)
                .Select(c => c.AccountingID).FirstOrDefault(),
            Period = tData.system_Times
                .Where(b => b.EmployeeID == x.Key.EmployeeID)
                .Select(c => c.Period).FirstOrDefault(),
            Status = tData.system_Times
                .Where(b => b.EmployeeID == x.Key.EmployeeID)
                .Select(c => c.Status).FirstOrDefault()
        }
    );

    return Times;
}
```

Although I've stated at the beginning of the statement to GroupBy both the EmployeeID and the Period, the output is still only grouping by the EmployeeID. The image below is the current output, which should be separated by Period and the EmployeeID, not just the EmployeeID.

[image: Current RadGrid]

What could be the problem with my statement, and how I can re-work it to **actually** GroupBy BOTH the Period, and EmployeeID?

Comment: I've condensed the code a bit to make it a little easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks unnecessarily long and complicated.  The short answer to your problem is that you don't really do anything with the grouping you have made.  There is plenty of room for improvement but it's not clear what your schema is, what data you want and how you want the data.  I believe something like this is what you are looking for:

```
var query = from time in tData.system_Times
            orderby time.Period, time.system_Employee.LName
            group time by new { time.Period, time.EmployeeID } into employeeTimes
            join employee in tData.system_Employees
                on employeeTimes.Key.EmployeeID equals employee.EmployeeID
            select new
            {
                Times = employeeTimes,
                TotalReg = employeeTimes.Where(time => time.PayCode == "211")
                                        .Sum(time => time.Hours),
                TotalOT = employeeTimes.Where(time => time.PayCode == "212")
                                       .Sum(time => time.Hours),
                TotalTrav = employeeTimes.Where(time => time.PayCode == "214")
                                         .Sum(time => time.Hours),
                TotalSub = employeeTimes.Where(time => time.PayCode == "251")
                                        .Sum(time => time.Hours),
                FName = employee.FName,
                LName = employee.LName,
                Div = employee.Dept,
                AccID = employee.AccountingID,
                Period = employeeTimes.Key.Period,
                Status = employeeTimes.First().Status,
            };
```

Comment: This managed to clean up my code immensely and also solve my problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should work as it is, but you're not using period in select use it as you use EmployeId

```
x.Key.Period
```